# Grab what is shown on the screen in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x11, wayland

I understand that in Linux a windowing system (X11, Wayland etc.) is responsible for rendering applications on the screen. I experimented with X11 but never got past obtaining single windows. I also read about Wayland. My question is, if I want to write an application that grabs whatever is shown on the screen, is there a way to get it on such a low-level (drm, dri, kms) that I am not dependent on the windowing system? What choices do these low-level APIs give me compared to the windowing system?

**EDIT**: I realized reading [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Wayland_problems#Screen_capture_is_not_available_with_usual_apps) that "One of the features of Wayland is its security design, which helps to guard the user against malicious apps. Apps can no longer see everything on the screen and spy on you. But that also means you cannot run a common application (like shutter or gtk-recordmydesktop) and use it to make a screenshot or a screencast of your desktop".

Comment: If you intend to use x11, you can use ximagesrc gstreamer plugin (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-ximagesrc.html) which readily captures and you coan store it to storage device.